# How to clear all form fields from code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

HTML has an input button type to reset all fields in a form to their initial state in one step: `<input type="reset" ... />`.

Is there a similar simple way to reset all form fields of an aspx page from code-behind? Or is it necessary to reset all controls one by one with `TextBox1.Text=string.Empty`, `TextBox2.Text=string.Empty`, etc. ?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Context is a simple Contact/"Send us a message" page with 8 asp:TextBoxes on the page (where the user enters the name, address, phone, email, message, etc.). Then he clicks on submit, the Onclick message handler in code-behind sends an email to some administrator, and all the form fields the user filled in should be emptied and he gets a notification in a label ("Message sent blabla..."). I want to have the form fields cleared to avoid that the user clicks again on submit and the same message is sent a second time.

Comment: Depending on what the scenario is, there could be several ways to clear them. Could you explain how you want this to work in your scenario?

Comment: @Mikael Svenson: I have added an "Update" to my question to answer your question. Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: In that case I propose to turn off the viewstate for the controls you want to clear as I have written in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need only write a fork for each type of control unless one of the control has something special that needs to be done to reset it.

```
foreach( var control in this.Controls )
{
    var textbox = control as TextBox;
    if (textbox != null)
        textbox.Text = string.Empty;

    var dropDownList = control as DropDownList;
    if (dropDownList != null)
        dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ...
}
```

**ADDITION** You asked how to clear controls even ones that are buried. To do that, you should create a recursive routine like so:

```
private void ClearControl( Control control )
{
    var textbox = control as TextBox;
    if (textbox != null)
        textbox.Text = string.Empty;

    var dropDownList = control as DropDownList;
    if (dropDownList != null)
        dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ...

    foreach( Control childControl in control.Controls )
    {
        ClearControl( childControl );
    }
}
```

So, you would call this by passing the page:

```
ClearControls( this );
```

Comment: You should probably include some recursion if you have databindings, controls inside templates and custom controls.

Comment: Nice simple thing! (will be especially simple in my case since I only have TextBoxes on the page). Thank you!

Comment: There is a problem: My TextBoxes are inside of the `Content` element for a `ContentPlaceHolder` because my page is derived from a MasterPage. The `this.Controls` collection contains only one element which is the MasterPage itself (or something derived from it) with the `ID=ctl00`. I was searching around in debugger but can't find any collection of objects which represent my TextBoxes.

Comment: @Slauma - I've amended my response so that you can recursively clear each control.

Comment: @Thomas: Great, it works! Thanks! (I only had to replace the anonymous `var` in the foreach loop by `Control` since the compiler complained that `childControl` is an `object` and not a `Control`).

Comment: @Slauma - I corrected my post accordingly. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 7):

Refer this link for more information

http://www.freshcodehub.com/Article/3/clear-all-fields-like-textbox-dropdownlist-checkbox-radiobutton-label-after-form-submission-in-aspnet-c

```
public void ClearControls(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))  //Clear TextBox
        {
            ((TextBox)(c)).Text = "";
        }
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList)))  //Clear DropDownList
        {
            ((DropDownList)(c)).ClearSelection();
        }
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox)))  //Clear CheckBox
        {
            ((CheckBox)(c)).Checked = false;
        }
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBoxList)))  //Clear CheckBoxList
        {
            ((CheckBoxList)(c)).ClearSelection();
        }
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton)))  //Clear RadioButton
        {
            ((RadioButton)(c)).Checked = false;
        }
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(RadioButtonList)))  //Clear RadioButtonList
        {
            ((RadioButtonList)(c)).ClearSelection();
        }
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(HiddenField)))  //Clear HiddenField
        {
            ((HiddenField)(c)).Value = "";
        }
        if ((c.GetType() == typeof(Label)))  //Clear Label
        {
            ((Label)(c)).Text = "";
        }
        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            ClearControls(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

using the manual approach of `String.Empty` for each and every Textbox or any other field will be cumbersome, also by using    `Response.Redirect();` it will be difficult to show any confirmation message or same. So, on reading so many blogs i have found a reliable approach so far:

```
    Public void reset(Control control)
    {
      foreach (Control x in control.Controls)
      {
        if (x is TextBox)
        {
            (x as TextBox).Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else if (x is DropDownList)
        {
            (x as DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0;
        } 
        .
        .
        reset(x);
      }
    }
```

use this code as `reset(this);` in your page wherever you want to reset or clear the values. At end of the `if` conditions do not forget to use the function recursively using the same

`Control` object x.

Answer (score 2):

Using `form.Controls.Clear()` is not such a good approach because it will clear the entire form and you will even lose all the buttons on the form.

Instead if you just want to clear all the form fields like text fields and radio buttons I would recommend you try the following:
If you have a Reset button “Button1” then  on click call a function `reset();`

In the reset function:

```
   protected void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      TextBox1.Text=""; //set equal to empty string to all fields
   }
```

Or redirect to same page by terminating the previous page

```
    protected void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Test2.aspx", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario the easiest way to clear the fields, in my opinion, is to turn off the ViewState (`EnableViewState=false`) of the controls you want to appear blank after the submit.

Or perhaps for the whole page unless there is some state you need.

Comment: Hm, I've just tested it (for one of TextBoxes and also the option to turn off the ViewState of the whole page). But it doesn't work: All TextBoxes are still filled after the postback.

Comment: If you do a regular postback (not ajax) with EnabledViewState=false on the page or a control, there should be no way those fields should have values, unless you set them in code somewhere.

Comment: I've created a test web site (one TextBox+one Button, EnableViewState="false" on page level and also for the TextBox): Same behaviour, Values in the TextBox are preserved after PostBack. I've googled a bit and found explanations: 1) http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article760-common-misconception-regarding-viewstate-and-textbox-.aspx and 2) http://geekswithblogs.net/AaronLi/archive/2007/05/20/112615.aspx

Comment: @Slauma Learn something new every day :)